# How to design class property containing a collection of translations? For patterns gurus

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am design pattern newbie, please help to properly organize classes.

My entity has a property '**name**' that should have several translations:

```
class Entity {
   private int id;
   private TranslationCollection name;
   ...
}
```

'**name**' - should contain a set of translations:

```
{
  'en': 'english word',
  'sp': 'spanish word',
  ... 
}
```

So I decided to make class '**Translation**':

```
class Translation {
  private string locale;
  private string value;
  public constructor (locale, value) { ... }
  ...
}
```

and class '**TranslationCollection**':

```
class TranslationCollection {
   private translationArray[];
   public constructor() { 
     this.translationArray = new array() 
   }
   public addTranslation(Translation translation) {
      translationArray.push(translation);
   }
   ...
}
```

and there is requirements:

```
1 locales could be only from 'listOfLocales' which is available only at runtime.
2 Translation collection could not have repeating locales.
3 Unit testable.
```

Is it normal to inject '**listOfLocales**' into '**Translation**' constructor to check locale is in the list? In that case I will have three parameters in '**Translation**' constructor. And I think it is not good design.

Or should I have some '**TranslationFactory**' with '**listOfLocales**' injected in the constructor to create Translation with proper locale?

Or may be I am on the wrong way, and there is a better solution?

An how to organize check that '**TranslationCollection**' has no repeating locales? Should I check in addTranslation method that there is no array items with locations matching new Translation.location programmatically, which seems not best solution. Is it a way to organize non repeating collection more declaratively?